# How can I delete my Area 51 account?

Tags: support, area-51, user-accounts

I joined Area 51 to propose a site for identify-my-rock questions (banned at Earth Sciences). The proposal was rejected and I edited [my profile](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/213914/delete) with "Please delete me".

That was three months ago and my account is still open.

I received an email with a link saying to be me who close the account. But this is what the link open.

[image]

It truely doesn't matter to me a lot whatever the account is deleted or no, just I am curious.

Comment: About broken link, probably a  new CM who doesn't even know what Area 51 is handled the ticket, so they just sent what they were taught  to send when someone asks to delete account. Your best option, IMO, would be directly asking a CM in a chat to do it.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Is Vaccinated V3 What I don't understand is if this happens to all users trying to delete his profile. I have yet sent them an email. It is ok, it doesn't matter truelly. I can allways hide my Area51 account in my profile.

Comment: It happens only for users trying to delete their Area 51 profile, because Area 51 is very.... different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the FAQ [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999)

> Area 51 profiles: As Area 51 runs off a significantly older version of the Stack Exchange software, the ability to delete your own account is not implemented there. You may request deletion of your Area 51 account by using the contact form there (choose "I need to delete my user profile", then close the dialog box).

So, go to the [Contact Us form at Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and follow the above instruction

If the Area 51 Contact Us page doesn't work for some reason, use any other site's [Contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form (footer of the page), choose "Other" and explain you want to delete your Area51 user profile. Maybe mention that the Area51 contact us option for account deletion is broken, if you tried that.

Comment: "mention that the Area51 contact us option for account deletion is broken" - they'll just reply "post bug report on meta".

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 sure, but it is more to prevent they delete the account from the site you posted the contact  form from. I don't assume the bug gets fixed, only to make sure they delete the correct profile.